# Parse a string into Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string which is of the form dictionary for sure.
I need to parse it and store it as a dictionary in python.

What i have tried is this:

```
myObj={}
tmp=""
if ':' in line:
    key,value = line.split(':')
    key = key.strip('"')
    value = value.lstrip(' ').rstrip(',')
    if value == '{':
        tmp += key + '.'
    if value == '}':
        tmp = ''
    if(value!="{"):
        myObj[tmp + key] = value
```

Reading Line by Line and parsing it. But I am facing problems with different kind of formats.

For E.G.

```
        {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        "price": 123,
        "tags": [ "Bar", "Eek" ],
        "stock": {
            "warehouse": 300,
            "retail": 20
        }
    }
```

No use of `eval` or any built in function or library like json. Can I use regex here? 
How do I do this?

Comment: Why *"No use of `eval` or any built in function or library"*?

Comment: Really, you are *explicitly excluding the provided library*? Note that `re` *is a library too*. You'll need to tell us **why** you have such arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: Then parsing will not have any meaning. I need to parse it.

Comment: You can't parse JSON with regex - it's [not a regular language](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language).

Comment: Then tell us what you have tried so far; writing a parser is not a trivial task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You have JSON data, use the [`json` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to parse it:

```
import json

data = json.loads(yourstring)
```

Python comes with batteries included, don't reinvent the wheel.